# Strange JS Issues

Tags: javascript

I am having hard time figuring it out what is the issue behind these errors on my prestashop built website:

```
JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 714: ';
JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 730: ';
JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 746: ';
JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 26113: ';
```

﻿one of the worse page is the one below:

Link:https://www.advantagelife.net/ladies-hand-and-sholder-bags/40-chw-ladie-s-summer-stylish-envelope-handbag.html

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried using any developing tool? http://prntscr.com/5v5zu0 This explains MUCH. Fix these first, then come back if you experience any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere missing the semicolon or quote.

Commands in JS can be terminated by new line (enter), when you minify the code, missing semicolon can cause this error message.

Comment: It's actually a problem with quotation marks, as evidenced by the words `Unterminated String` :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for this line of code:

```
var productName = 'ChW: Ladie's Summer Stylish Envelope Handbag';
```

You either need to use double quotes to surround the string, or escape that apostrophe in "Ladie's". (The correct spelling is "Ladies'" btw).

Escape it with a backslash: `Ladies\'`

You've also got a number of other errors like jQuery not loading, but I think this is the one it's complaining about.